# How Google saves searched pages and keywords of every users?

Tags: google-search

This is a known fact that Google keeps a record for keywords searched and web pages visited by every user so that it gives personalized results.

Now my question is a how does it saves user data in a database? that will be huge task coz that will be billions of keywords and url.

In layman terms is it possible to have table of records with users as one column and keywords/urls in other columns?

I am curious to know what are the latest technologies or methods to do such a task?

Comment: Probably http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable. Googles front end is not PHP and it doesn't use mySQL for this as far as I know so I'm removing those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know about `big table`:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/de//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf

**Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data**
a very good paper!